# IBM ODM - Errors when upgrading from Classic to Decision Engine within Rule Designer 8.12

Tags: ibm-odm

I have classic engine rule projects from ODM 8.9, and I am wanting to upgrade them to Decision Engine in ODM 8.12.

Once I make the change in Rule Designer, I get many of these errors:

[B2X] GBREX0001E: Cannot find execution class 'com.****.businessrules.claims.virtualdomain.Assessment' for translating business class 'com.****.businessrules.claims.virtualdomain.Assessment'

[B2X] GBREX0009E: Mismatch of member type, type 'java.lang.String' is returned by member 'com.****.businessrules.claims.domain.ClaimEvent.eventType', whereas the type 'com.****.businessrules.claims.virtualdomain.EventType' or a subclass is expected.

[B2X] GBREX0011E: Cannot find method 'getClaimEventCountbyType(com.****.businessrules.claims.virtualdomain.EventType,com.****.businessrules.claims.domain.Claim)' in execution class 'com.****.businessrules.claims.extenders.ClaimExtender'

I have updated and checked everything i can think of:

java versions/jre/compiler

build path

project references

execution model setting

object model origins

Looking for some assistance please on how to resolve these to complete decision engine upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely in one of the element you already mentioned :

- java project references (eventually exporting transitive dependancies)
- project references + execution project references
- bom settings (eventually bom order)

Best
Emmanuel